# OnClick after OnClientClick in vb.net button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, events, click

I've got a web page that has the following situation:
I want to upload a file, but instead of using a fileupload and then a button to upload, i want a button to launch the browse for files, and when i click OK it uploads the file.
I use a javascript function to launch fileupload (onclientclick of my button) but then nothing else happens, i.e, it doesn't go to the onclick on the codebehind

Comment: `return true` should carry on with the `PostBack`.

Comment: already tried it... it doesn't work sadly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call a function from the OnClick call, like:

```
function fileUpload() {
    //your function to call the JavaScript file selection
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Well, calling the javascript function to browse worked, and then it goes to the onclick... although there is still an issue: FileUploader.HasFile is always getting false, even when I see the link to the file on it's textbox. Can it be some crazy postback?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I've seen that happen when the file uploader is inside an update panel...

Comment: Actually it is inside an UpdatePanel but I've removed it and the result was the same, and also I've put the postbacktrigger on the button and it didn't caught the file (at least not in the property HasFile, because viisually I see text on the fileupload....)

Answer (score 0):

Place the JavaScript function in the OnClick function and then return true, passing control to the code behind.

Comment: can you please explain a bit better? document.getElementById('<%= FileUploader.ClientID%>').click();
              
                return true;